# A RenderFlex overflowed by 230 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter

I keep getting this error and I know how to fix it I've tried wrapping my column inside an Expanded and a Flexible widget but it doesn't seem to be working.
Here's my code :

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          //To Show Current Date
          Container(
            height: 30,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          //To show Calendar Widget

          Expanded(

              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex : 2,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Card(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              const ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  'MISSIONS',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                      fontSize: 20),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex : 8,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 600.0,
                      child: ListView.builder(

                          itemCount:
                              3,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {


                            // box.put('missionName', missionName);
                            //box.put("entries",entries);

                            //var name = box.get('missionName');

                            //print('Name: $name');

                            return GestureDetector(
                              child: Card(
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 110,
                                    child: Row(


                                      children: <Widget>[


                                        Expanded(

                                            child: Text(
                                                'mission'),


                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(height: 30),
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: GestureDetector(
                                            child: Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                               child: Column(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                            // Just a top space

                                            // main content
                                            Container(
                                              child: Stack(
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  // Box and icons
                                                  Stack(
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                      // Box
                                                      renderBox(),

                                                      // Icons
                                                      renderIcons(),
                                                    ],
                                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                                  ),

                                                  // Button like
                                                  renderBtnLike(),

                                                  // Icons when jump
                                                  // Icon like
                                                  whichIconUserChoose == 1 && !isDragging
                                                      ? Container(
                                                    child: Transform.scale(
                                                      child: Image.asset(
                                                        "images/close.png",
                                                        width: 20.0,
                                                        height: 20.0,
                                                      ),
                                                      scale: this.zoomIconWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: processTopPosition(this.moveUpIconWhenRelease.value),
                                                      left: this.moveLeftIconLikeWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                      : Container(),

                                                  // Icon love
                                                  whichIconUserChoose == 2 && !isDragging
                                                      ? Container(
                                                    child: Transform.scale(
                                                      child: Image.asset(
                                                        "images/nowork.png",
                                                        width: 20.0,
                                                        height: 20.0,
                                                      ),
                                                      scale: this.zoomIconWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: processTopPosition(this.moveUpIconWhenRelease.value),
                                                      left: this.moveLeftIconLoveWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                      : Container(),

                                                  // Icon haha
                                                  whichIconUserChoose == 3 && !isDragging
                                                      ? Container(
                                                    child: Transform.scale(
                                                      child: Image.asset(
                                                        "images/sunny.png",
                                                        width: 20.0,
                                                        height: 20.0,
                                                      ),
                                                      scale: this.zoomIconWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: processTopPosition(this.moveUpIconWhenRelease.value),
                                                      left: this.moveLeftIconHahaWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                      : Container(),


                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                                              // Area of the content can drag
                                              // decoration:  BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                                              width: double.infinity,

                                            ),
                                            ],
                                          ),

                                            ),

                                            onHorizontalDragEnd: onHorizontalDragEndBoxIcon,
                                            onHorizontalDragUpdate: onHorizontalDragUpdateBoxIcon,
                                          ),
                                        )


                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 30),

                ],
              )),


        ],
      ),
    );
```

This is the  renderBtnLike() widget :

```
Widget renderBtnLike() {
    return Container(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTapDown: onTapDownBtn,
        onTapUp: onTapUpBtn,
        onTap: onTapBtn,
        child: Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              // Icon like
              Expanded(
                child: Transform.scale(
                  child: Transform.rotate(
                    child: Image.asset(
                      getImageIconBtn(),
                      width: 10.0,
                      height: 10.0,
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      color: getTintColorIconBtn(),
                    ),
                    angle:
                    !isLongPress ? handleOutputRangeTiltIconLike(tiltIconLikeInBtn2.value) : tiltIconLikeInBtn.value,
                  ),
                  scale:
                  !isLongPress ? handleOutputRangeZoomInIconLike(zoomIconLikeInBtn2.value) : zoomIconLikeInBtn.value,
                ),
              ),

              // Text like
              Expanded(
                child: Transform.scale(
                  child: Text(
                    getTextBtn(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: getColorTextBtn(),
                      fontSize: 8.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  scale:
                  !isLongPress ? handleOutputRangeZoomInIconLike(zoomIconLikeInBtn2.value) : zoomTextLikeInBtn.value,
                ),
              ),
            ],
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      ),
      width: 100.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border.all(color: getColorBorderBtn()),
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    );
  }
```

If anyone seems to know the answer please tell me how to fix this and thank you in advance.

Comment: Wrap `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

you just need to wrap your Column widget into SingleChildScrollView widget to get rid of and Expanded and Flexible widgets works inside Column or Row

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child : Column(
        children: [
          //To Show Current Date
          Container(
            height: 30,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          //To show Calendar Widget

          Expanded(

              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex : 2,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Card(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              const ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  'MISSIONS',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                      fontSize: 20),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex : 8,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 600.0,
                      child: ListView.builder(

                          itemCount:
                              3,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {


                            // box.put('missionName', missionName);
                            //box.put("entries",entries);

                            //var name = box.get('missionName');

                            //print('Name: $name');

                            return GestureDetector(
                              child: Card(
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 110,
                                    child: Row(


                                      children: <Widget>[


                                        Expanded(

                                            child: Text(
                                                'mission'),


                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(height: 30),
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: GestureDetector(
                                            child: Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                               child: Column(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                            // Just a top space

                                            // main content
                                            Container(
                                              child: Stack(
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  // Box and icons
                                                  Stack(
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                      // Box
                                                      renderBox(),

                                                      // Icons
                                                      renderIcons(),
                                                    ],
                                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                                  ),

                                                  // Button like
                                                  renderBtnLike(),

                                                  // Icons when jump
                                                  // Icon like
                                                  whichIconUserChoose == 1 && !isDragging
                                                      ? Container(
                                                    child: Transform.scale(
                                                      child: Image.asset(
                                                        "images/close.png",
                                                        width: 20.0,
                                                        height: 20.0,
                                                      ),
                                                      scale: this.zoomIconWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: processTopPosition(this.moveUpIconWhenRelease.value),
                                                      left: this.moveLeftIconLikeWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                      : Container(),

                                                  // Icon love
                                                  whichIconUserChoose == 2 && !isDragging
                                                      ? Container(
                                                    child: Transform.scale(
                                                      child: Image.asset(
                                                        "images/nowork.png",
                                                        width: 20.0,
                                                        height: 20.0,
                                                      ),
                                                      scale: this.zoomIconWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: processTopPosition(this.moveUpIconWhenRelease.value),
                                                      left: this.moveLeftIconLoveWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                      : Container(),

                                                  // Icon haha
                                                  whichIconUserChoose == 3 && !isDragging
                                                      ? Container(
                                                    child: Transform.scale(
                                                      child: Image.asset(
                                                        "images/sunny.png",
                                                        width: 20.0,
                                                        height: 20.0,
                                                      ),
                                                      scale: this.zoomIconWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: processTopPosition(this.moveUpIconWhenRelease.value),
                                                      left: this.moveLeftIconHahaWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                      : Container(),


                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                                              // Area of the content can drag
                                              // decoration:  BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                                              width: double.infinity,

                                            ),
                                            ],
                                          ),

                                            ),

                                            onHorizontalDragEnd: onHorizontalDragEndBoxIcon,
                                            onHorizontalDragUpdate: onHorizontalDragUpdateBoxIcon,
                                          ),
                                        )


                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 30),

                ],
              )),


        ],
      ),
     ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return Scaffold(
      body: singlechildscrollview(
        child:Column(
        children: [
          //To Show Current Date
          Container(
            height: 30,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          //To show Calendar Widget

          Expanded(

              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex : 2,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Card(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              const ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  'MISSIONS',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                      fontSize: 20),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex : 8,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 600.0,
                      child: ListView.builder(

                          itemCount:
                              3,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {


                            // box.put('missionName', missionName);
                            //box.put("entries",entries);

                            //var name = box.get('missionName');

                            //print('Name: $name');

                            return GestureDetector(
                              child: Card(
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 110,
                                    child: Row(


                                      children: <Widget>[


                                        Expanded(

                                            child: Text(
                                                'mission'),


                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(height: 30),
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: GestureDetector(
                                            child: Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                               child: Column(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                            // Just a top space

                                            // main content
                                            Container(
                                              child: Stack(
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  // Box and icons
                                                  Stack(
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                      // Box
                                                      renderBox(),

                                                      // Icons
                                                      renderIcons(),
                                                    ],
                                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                                  ),

                                                  // Button like
                                                  renderBtnLike(),

                                                  // Icons when jump
                                                  // Icon like
                                                  whichIconUserChoose == 1 && !isDragging
                                                      ? Container(
                                                    child: Transform.scale(
                                                      child: Image.asset(
                                                        "images/close.png",
                                                        width: 20.0,
                                                        height: 20.0,
                                                      ),
                                                      scale: this.zoomIconWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: processTopPosition(this.moveUpIconWhenRelease.value),
                                                      left: this.moveLeftIconLikeWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                      : Container(),

                                                  // Icon love
                                                  whichIconUserChoose == 2 && !isDragging
                                                      ? Container(
                                                    child: Transform.scale(
                                                      child: Image.asset(
                                                        "images/nowork.png",
                                                        width: 20.0,
                                                        height: 20.0,
                                                      ),
                                                      scale: this.zoomIconWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: processTopPosition(this.moveUpIconWhenRelease.value),
                                                      left: this.moveLeftIconLoveWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                      : Container(),

                                                  // Icon haha
                                                  whichIconUserChoose == 3 && !isDragging
                                                      ? Container(
                                                    child: Transform.scale(
                                                      child: Image.asset(
                                                        "images/sunny.png",
                                                        width: 20.0,
                                                        height: 20.0,
                                                      ),
                                                      scale: this.zoomIconWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: processTopPosition(this.moveUpIconWhenRelease.value),
                                                      left: this.moveLeftIconHahaWhenRelease.value,
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                      : Container(),


                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                                              // Area of the content can drag
                                              // decoration:  BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                                              width: double.infinity,

                                            ),
                                            ],
                                          ),

                                            ),

                                            onHorizontalDragEnd: onHorizontalDragEndBoxIcon,
                                            onHorizontalDragUpdate: onHorizontalDragUpdateBoxIcon,
                                          ),
                                        )


                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 30),

                ],
              )),


        ],
      ),
    );
   );
```